# Wordpress Ajax - looping data into a table

Tags: ajax, wpdb

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? I made an ajax call in wordpress to loop through data to display the results on a table.

Here is my php:

```
    function DisplayInfo() {

    global $wpdb;

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];


    
        $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM students");
    
        echo "<div value='".$first_name."'>".$first_name."</div>"; // test
        foreach($data as $student)
            {
                echo '<tr>'; 
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress1" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">'; // This line displays a button each time looped through
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<form>'; 
                                echo '<td>' . $student->first_name . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $student->last_name . '</td>';
                    echo '</form>';
                echo '</tr>';
                
            }
}
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
echo '<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: {
         "key" : {first_name, last_name},
        "action": "fetch_data" // very important
    },
    success : function (data) {
             console.log(data);
             jQuery("#result").html(data);
            }
});

</script>';
```

Finally, how I call the everything on my page:

```
echo '<div id="result"></div>';
```

Comment: how is `DisplayInfo` being called? If it did not do what you expected it to do, what did it do instead? You haven't shared the problem with us so it's difficult to know what the issue is. Also you're using `first_name` and `last_name` but I do not see them in your AJAX call, I only see a `key` field which is never referenced in the PHP

Comment: Where is this echo happening? (your ajax call portion of code) Is it late enough that jquery has been loaded before the script data has been output?

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually added this action through functions.php?

This might be of interest for you:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/

in your case the php function needs to be added as a hook:
`add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_data', 'DisplayInfo')`
`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_data', 'DisplayInfo')`

Comment: The action in the code posted is `fetch_data`. It doesn't matter what you name your callback function, only that it hooks the correct action name, or inversely that your ajax call action matches the hook your callback is attached to.

Comment: aahh sorry I copied the wrong action name, you're right! Let me edit it